# Switch Front Camera ARToolkit Unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I'm using `ARToolkit` with `Unity` to create a AR application for `Android` and `iOS`. My main problem is that I can not switch between back camera and the front one. Is there any way accomplish this using `C#`?

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation here: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_video_capture

section 'AR_VIDEO_DEVICE_IPHONE' you can specify the camera using the parameter:
'-position=X'

So as it looks you can do this for your application in the configuration. However you question sounds like you would like to do this dynamically.

A start could be to call the function:
PluginFunctions.arwStartRunningB(...)

with the defined configuration including the '-position=X' parameter. Of cause you would need to call 'arwStopRunning' before you can call arwStartRunningB again.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: This might work for iOS but unfortunately not Android. I've been trying to find an answer for the past few hours but `-position=front` caused my Android application to not be able to find a camera at all.